# «Ir ter a» e «ir ter com» — qual é a origem destas expressões?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, origem

Estas duas expressões idiomáticas são muito comuns em Portugal. Quanto ao Brasil, elas vêm no [Michaelis (ter 48)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=ter) e são muito frequentes na literatura do século XIX. Atualmente parecem ser pouco comuns (ver comentários) mas ainda se encontram nalguns autores (incluo dois exemplos abaixo).

***Ir ter a*** significa ’chegar a, ir parar a, desembocar’:

> Seguimos por um atalho, e ***fomos ter a*** uma casa abandonada.
>
> Este caminho ***vai ter à*** estrada principal.
>
> Se subisse sempre, ***iria ter à*** avenida Paulista. [[Maria de Lourdes Teixeira, *Rua Augusta*, 1963.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mYlVAAAAMAAJ&q=Se%20subisse%20sempre,%20iria%20ter%20%C3%A0%20avenida%20Paulista&dq=Se%20subisse%20sempre,%20iria%20ter%20%C3%A0%20avenida%20Paulista&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjet7jPl8bMAhXT0RoKHcACBaQQ6AEIJTAA)

***Ir ter com*** significa ’dirigir-se a (alguém), ir encontrar-se com (alguém)’:

> ***Vou ter contigo*** às cinco horas.
>
> [...] meu companheiro, fiado na amizade que granjeara entre os gentios, ***iria ter com*** eles, a ver se o aceitavam como hóspede. [[Álvaro Cardoso Gomes, *Os Rios Inúmeráveis*, 1997.]](https://www.google.pt/search?q=iria%20ter%20com%20eles,%20a%20ver%20se%20o%20aceitavam%20como%20h%C3%B3spede&num=100&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilj4u7mMbMAhXF2RoKHd3MCIYQ_AUIDSgB&biw=1242&bih=585)

O significado de ***ir*** nestas expressões ainda se compreende, mas o de ***ter*** é mais enigmático. Donde vêm estas expressões e quando começaram a ser usadas?

Comment: Creio serem exclusivas de pt-PT.  Entendemos perfeitamente o significado mas não são de uso de uso corrente em pt-BR.

Comment: @Centaurus Interessante. Encontro *ir ter com* com alguma frequência em autores brasileiros do século XX; *ir ter a* é menos frequente, mas também encontro. Agora o curioso é que no séc. XIX estas expressões são de longe muito mais comuns nos autores brasileiros que nos portugueses. Vou incluir alguns exemplos na pergunta.

Comment: Jacinto, sim, diversos escritores brasileiros usaram a expressão, menos frequentemente agora no século XXI.  Na língua falada, no entanto, imagino que seja muito raro.  A mim soa como algo saído de um livro da primeira metade do século XX.

Comment: Dom Casmurro: "Minha mãe assoou-se sem responder. Prima Justina creio que se levantou e foi ter com ela."

Comment: @AndréLyra Neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/x.asp) encontras dúzias de *ir ter com* e *ir ter a* de autores brasileiros do século XIX, incluindo do Machado de Assis. Pelo menos na literatura estas expressões eram até bem mais populares no Brasil que em Portugal.

Comment: Poderia significar discussão?

Comment: @AndréLyra *Ir ter com alguém* significa *dirigir-se a alguém, ir encontrar-se com alguém*, como explico na pergunta. Em Portugal é a forma mais comum de exprimir esta ideia. Imagina que estávamos a falar ao telefone; eu poderia dizer «estou no café Vanicelos; ***vem ter comigo***».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maria José Carvalho tem no seu artigo [*Aspetos Sociocognitivos da Variação e da Mudança Semântica: Haver e Ter em Estruturas de Posse*](http://www.scielo.mec.pt/pdf/dia/v28n1/v28n1a14.pdf)  a explicação (pág. 372):

> #### *2.5*. Teer *com sentido de ‘desembocar’*
>
> A lexia complexa “ir ter” (‘desembocar em’, ‘intersetar’) documenta-se
>   igualmente no nosso *corpus*, em documentos das últimas décadas do século
>   XV e primeiro quartel do século XVI, substituindo a estrutura trecentista
>   “ir ferir”. Recordamos, a esse propósito, a perífrase que se documenta no
>   século XIV para transmitir essa noção:
>
> (i) «como *uay ferir* ſuſo» (1321 Alc 17)
>   (ii) «*uã ferir* ao rrio de Selir» (1321 Alc 17)
>   (iii) «*uã ferir* aa varz(ea) (1321 Alc 17)
>   (iv) «*uã ferir* aa ponte» (1321 Alc 17)
>
> As abonações quatrocentistas e quinhentistas exibem o verbo *ter* neste
>   contexto, refletindo uma extensão tardia à noção de ‘intersetar’:
>
> (v) «(…), e eſto do camjnho que uay da ponte noua pera o porto de Muja atee o Tejo e do camjnho pera çima a *ter* o camjnho de Meos» (1478 MA 122)
>   (vi) «(…) o quall aſentamento parte do abrigo com as cabaceeyrras, e de hy ſe vay a rrebeyrra (…) e da paarte do agujã vay *teer* ao outeyrro do careyrro e per hy affondo per o Vall de Froles e vay *teer* a ffonte » (1500 MA 136)
>   (vii) «e por quanto o dito moſteiro eſtaua ẽ poſſe de tanto tenpo que memoria dos homẽs nõ he ẽ contrairo, rreçeber e aver todalas couſas que ſaem e vem *ter* aos portos e coſta do maar» (1515 SM 141)
>   (viii) «(…) aſy dos taes pexes rreaes como de todalas outras couſas que ſaẽ e vẽ *ter* haa coſta do dito maar» (1515 SM 141)
>
> Como se pode inferir, o sujeito da oração não é a entidade que “tem”,
>   já que este é captado cognitivamente como a entidade que interseta, identificando-se o “objeto” intersetado com uma espécie de locativo.

Comment: Muito interessante. Continuo intrigado com o entendimento do *ter* nestas frases. *Ferir* quase que se percebe melhor: *Ferir* = *atingir*. Como é que escreves o ***s*** longo?

Comment: @Jacinto Linux e similares: Compose, f, s.

Comment: Olha lá, e sobre o *ir ter com (alguém)*? Não encontraste nada?